# error: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-const-variable'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]

Tags: macos

I recently started getting this error:

```
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-const-variable'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

when compiling my codebase on mac os 12.2.1. I don't think I was getting this "error" on a previous mac os version -- I think it used to be a warning. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't know about the `-Wno-unused-but-set-variable` option anymore?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3622